# Is there a way to avoid a jupyter notebook from total crash and restart when a single cell is running out of memory?

Tags: python-3.x, memory, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, kaggle

While running a jupyter notebook on Kaggle kernel, assume that one cell (half way in the middle of the code or close to the end) is crashing due to memory allocation. The consequence is that this crash generalizes simultaneously to the entire notebook which causes nothing to be saved along the way and the notebook to be restarted. Then, you have no option but to run the entire notebook from the beginning. So, I am wondering if there is a way to avoid this, i.e. meaning limiting the crash only to the said cell so that we just debug that single cell instead of running the entire code all over again.